# How to debug in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I am trying to debug an iOS app in Xcode. My scheme is with the Build Configuration in Debug. When I run the application, the Debug panel opens but when the application opens in the simulator or on the device, the panel closes and does not allow me to debug.

What are the conditions that must be met in order to debug an application in Xcode?

My Xcode version is 11.3.1.
My macOS version is 10.15.2.

**Update 1**

I put image of my configurations:

[image]

When I try to attach the debug to simulator by "Attach to Process by PID or Name..." I have the following error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you put any breakpoints?

Comment: Yes, I already did that.

Comment: What is "the Debug panel" that "opens" and "closes"? Show a screen shot of what you're talking about, please.

Comment: Also please prove (1) that you have breakpoints and (2) breakpoints are _active_ and _enabled_.

Comment: To try to debug it, set your active scheme in Xcode to be AppName > iPhone 11 Pro Max.  Then using the simulator alone (not Xcode) click on the AppName to let it run.  Then go into Xcode and do Debug > Attach to process by PID.  Then type in the name of your App, and click Attach.  Then press the Pause icon in Xcode Debug Navigator.  Does it attach to your app.  Does it pause your app?

Comment: @matt see update 2, the first image prove that my breakpoints is active. The Debug panel is the Debug area, when you run the app from Xcode opens the Debug area and show Debug navigator.

Comment: Don't you think the "lost connection" dialog might have been good to mention in the original question?

Comment: I think the problem is not having developer mode enabled.  See my updated answer below to query its status and set it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scheme you are running must be enabled for Debugging.  This is the default but it might have been changed, by accident, or during experimentation.

Here is a correct example, enabling debug.

[image]

Ensure you have set some breakpoints.

Furthermore, it might be that your preference settings are incorrect for debugging.

The following settings need to be checked in Xcode > Preferences; Behaviour Tab.

Note two checked items for the Running Pauses left panel selection:

[image: Behaviour Preferences[1]]

Note that when Xcode is installed, upon first use it will prompt for Developer Access to your system requiring a password for the Administrator privileged account (normally your own account has such privilege).

In order for debug attach to work, Developer Mode must be enabled.  This can be checked:

```
# DevToolsSecurity -verbose -status
Getting rights definition for: system.privilege.taskport.debug
Current rights definition dictionary:
"k-of-n" : 1
"class" : "rule"
"created" : 582290628
"version" : 0
"modified" : 589046609
"comment" : "For use by Apple.  WARNING: administrators are advised
            not to modify this right."
"rule" : { "is-admin", "is-developer", "authenticate-developer" }

Developer mode is currently enabled.
```

To enable developer mode if it is not enabled, use

`# sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable`

Comment: I enable the developer mode and has the same issue. What I tried is to debug another simple application and I succeeded, only with one application does that happen to me.

Comment: From a terminal you could run `lldb` and then provide the command `process attach -n "vaion" --waitfor --verbose` replacing vaion with the name of your app.  Then whilst in the simulator launch the app.  Compare the outputs between the app that works and the app that fails and share the output with us.  Maybe Erase and Reset Settings within the Simulator also in case of a bad build.

Comment: Here the output:
`Process 3712 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x000000010e1dc000 dyld`_dyld_start
dyld`_dyld_start:
->  0x10e1dc000 <+0>: popq   %rdi
    0x10e1dc001 <+1>: pushq  $0x0
    0x10e1dc003 <+3>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10e1dc006 <+6>: andq   $-0x10, %rsp
Target 0: (My App) stopped.

Executable module set to "/Users/user1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84F9F90F-F374-45A5-AD01-8D0B76B1208B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4C4C8558-A7B8-4B5B-A9CB-59C919D1322A/My App.app/My App".
Architecture set to: x86_64h-apple-ios-.`

Comment: That looks like a good attach.  Also it says "user1" whereas people normally have "johndoe" or something as their user account.  Is it a shared or temporary machine, or guest account, or lower privileged account?  If lldb can attach but Xcode cannot, I recommend deleting and reinstalling Xcode.  Worth reporting to Apple if that does not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Put breakpoints to your code whatever you want to debug by clicking the number of line.

[image]

Hope it helps...

Comment: I already did that and it didn't work out for me. The debug panel should at least remain open as an indicator that debug is activated but it is not, just the application opens the panel closes and does not stay at the breakpoints I put.

Comment: Can you share an image?

Comment: @ffcc , I see this error too. After several restart Xcode returns to normal :)